# Electron.js and React. Build contains huge node_modules

Tags: reactjs, node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I'm building a small application with `electron.js` and `react` (my first app of this kind).
I use `electron-packager` for builds. The problem is that my builds contain all my node modules. I use my built react app in production though.
I thought, maybe I should use separate `node_modules` for my react part and node part. I mean, in this case it would copy only the packages which are used in node. It's just a few small packages like `dotenv`.

**Here you can see the npm scripts:**

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "electron": "electron index.js",
    "release-win": "electron-packager ./ mailer --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --overwrite",
    "release-darwin": "electron-packager ./ mailer --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --overwrite",
    "release-linux": "electron-packager ./ mailer --platform=linux --arch=x64 --overwrite",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

**That's how the window is created:**

```
function createWindow() {
  // Build desktop window
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  });

  // Add developer tools in dev mode only
  if(isDev)
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Remove top menu with dev-actions in production
  if(!isDev)
    mainWindow.removeMenu();

  // Load environment variables form .env
  dotenv.config({
    path: path.join(__dirname, './.env')
  });

  // Load url:
  // - In dev it's loaded from localhost - react dev server with hot reloads and other features
  // - In prod it's loads built application
  mainWindow.loadURL(
      isDev
          ? 'http://localhost:3000' // Development server URL
          : `file://${path.join(__dirname, './build/index.html')}` // Production build path
  );

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}
```

Comment: I’m not sure I understand—how would having multiple node_modules help? Electron apps are Node apps with a front end (React in your case). You need both.

Comment: `I'm building a small application with electron.js` - have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Since you use React, and more specifically in your case [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/), you have [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) that can bundle the files for you, and save you from packging `node_modules` completely. Given this, one solution for your issue is to change the webpack configuration to include your Electron files in the bundle, and then to configure `electron-packager` to only package the bundled files.

#### 1. Configure `webpack` to bundle your Electron code

Because they use Node.js, Electron files can't be bundled with the same configuration as for React (browser) files. So to include them in the bundle, you can't just add an [entry point](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/), you actually need to add an [extra configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations) for your main process code (and you can also do the same for the preload, if you have one).

When not [ejected](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject), CRA offers little or no possibility of editing the bundler's configuration. So to edit it without ejecting, you can use a tool such as [`craco`](https://github.com/dilanx/craco) or [`react-app-rewired`](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired). I never used Craco, so I can only give you an example of configuration for Rewired:

**config-overrides.js**

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    const electronMainConfig = {
      target: "electron-main",
      mode: "production",
      entry: path.join(__dirname, "electron", "main.js"), // Input path
      output: {
        ...config.output,
        filename: "static/js/electron.main.js" // Output path (minus `build`)
      }
    }

    return process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
      ? config
      : [config, electronMainConfig]
  }
};
```

On this example, `main.js` is in `electron/main.js` and it will be bundled as `build/static/js/electron.main.js`. In developement, the default original config is used.

The important part is the [`target`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/): for the main process `electron-main` can be used, for the preload it would be `electron-preload`. Unlike the `browserslist` target ([which is used for your renderer, React code](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/0a827f69ab0d2ee3871ba9b71350031d8a81b7ae/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L200)), these targets are compatible with the Node.js code of your Electron files.

---

Note that on build you will get the error:

```bash
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'publicPath')
```

This is because CRA was not configured to handle multiple webpack configurations. It will not break the process so it can be ignored ([for reference](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/issues/629#issuecomment-1226896841)).

---

Now, to load the app in the window you can use:

```js
app.isPackaged
  ? mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "../../index.html")) // Prod
  : mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:3000"); // Dev
```

With this configuration, all your files should be neatly bundled inside your `build` folder.

#### 2. Configure `electron-packager` to only package the bundled files

Now that you have a `build` folder containing everything you need, you want to tell `electron-packager` that it should only package this folder (and the `package.json`, which I'm pretty sure is mandatory). As [I gathered](https://github.com/electron/packager/issues/972), `electron-packager` only provide an [`ignore`](https://electron.github.io/packager/main/interfaces/Options.html#ignore) option for the files you *don't* want to package. In command line, it should look something like:

```bash
--ignore=^\\/(?!(build|package\\.json))
```

I can't test this so I'm not 100% sure about the syntax, but this is based on a configuration shared [here](https://github.com/electron/packager/issues/972#issuecomment-886094684).

#### 3. Use the correct `main` entry point in production

The main entry point is the one specified on your `package.json`, as required by Electron. In production, you want it to be the path to your main file in the `build` folder. This part is a little tricky because `electron-packager` doesn't seem to provide an option to change it while packaging (or I have not found it), so it means you either need to do it manually every time you want to package, or use a script to do it for you. Here is [a small script](https://gist.github.com/Arkellys/cb20d535daaf54ed7bb3b72cfbef1d93) I've used when I needed to do this.

An example of usage with the script in `bin/change-entry-point.js`, your main file in `electron/main.js`, the module [`cross-env`](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) and [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/):

```json
"set-entry-point": "node ./bin/change-entry-point.js"
"start": "cross-env ENTRY_PATH=electron/index.js yarn set-entry-point && react-app-rewired start",
"build": "(react-app-rewired build || exit 0)",
"package:win": "cross-env ENTRY_PATH=build/static/js/electron-main.js yarn set-entry-point && yarn build && yarn release-win",
...
```

The `exit 0` on the `build` script is to prevent the process to stop when it encounters the error I mentioned on step 1.

This command will bundle your files for production and then package them using your command `release-win`:

```bash
yarn package:win
```

---

##### Alternative

If you're looking for a simplier way to package your app without the need to add a  custom script, I would suggest to replace `electron-packager` with [`electron-builder`](https://www.electron.build/index.html), this way you can do **steps 2 and 3** with the following configuration:

```js
"build": {
  "files": ["./build/**/*"], // What you want to package
  "extraMetadata": {
    "main": "build/static/js/electron.main.js" // Main entry in prod
  },
  "extends": null, // Disables `react-cra` preset to prevent error with paths
  // ...
},
```

See the [official docs](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#configuration) for more info on this configuration.